# Kendo UI; How to add event handler function on button of a form inside a Kendo WINDOW?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-events

I have a form inside a Kendo window, I an unable to trigger event on button click.

Comment: Sridhar's suggestion should work (see http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/BF69c) if it doesn't, create a demo of your problem

Comment: Thanks Sridhar and Lars see this http://jsfiddle.net/3Q8Bv/
It only works once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'IDorClassOfYourButton', function() {
    //Handle your event here.
})
```

Comment: Works perfect on normal html, but not in Kendo UI Window